# Regex parsing between 1 or more strings

Tags: regex, parsing

I have a regular expression `(?<=\d\b)(.*)(?=ave)` which simply finds the string between *digits* and `ave`. Example: `12234 dragon ave` will come out as `dragon`.

However let's assume that some addresses have optional `E(east),W(west),S(south),N(north) or NE, SE` etc. Example `122234 E dragon ave`. What should my regex look like so that it can only parse `dragon` part again?

Comment: is that dragon part will get repeated? if not then why cant you use only `(dragon)` in your regex.

Comment: database contain over 1 million data, so it is only dragon..

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=\d\b)\s*\S*\s(\S+)\s(?=ave)
```

You can use something of this sort and grab the group.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/jX1rN4/2

Comment: what if only want to exclude "N,S,W,E,North,West,NE"...for instance: "100 old maple ave", I only want to extract "old maple" part. Also, 100 N old maple ave" as only "old maple"

Comment: @ThomasDalls then u need to use something like `(?<=\d\b)\s*(?:N|S|W|E|North|West|NE)*\s(.*?)\s(?=ave)`

Comment: still checking my results (big data) but it seems to be working OK! One more question, let's say that the field is only "100 old maple " (No ave). Since the field does not have an "ave"(prohibited the string), I only want to see the "old maple" part of it. Can i do that?

Comment: @ThomasDalls yes u can

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `awk` for this?

```
awk 'NF==4{ print $3 } NF==3{ print $2 }' </tmp/addresses.txt
```

Here's what `addresses.txt` looks like:

```
12345 E Dragon ave
13 diagonal ave
1235 West Cherrytree ave
```

Notice this has limitations. For instance how would you handle addresses like:

```
1235 West Cherry Tree ave
```

This makes me wonder, do you just want to avoid house numbers, cardinal directions and streets / avenues / etc? It's important to understand what your inputs may be because this can really determine the what your script may look like.

Comment: I can't use awk..but it seems to be a better option

Answer (score 0):

An alternative idea is to capture each word in between the numbers and "ave", like this regex:

```
(?<=\d\b)(\s[a-zA-z]+\s)(.*)(?=[ave]*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/rU0lK1/3

**EDIT**

I saw your comments on vk's answer about optionally capturing the "ave" string, so I've updated regex101 demo and "ave" string capture.